# What are Generic Collections in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to build my first generic list and have run into some problems. I understand the declaration looks like " `List<T>` ", and I have `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of my page. However, Visual Studio doesn't recognize the `T` variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't feel bad, I went through the exact same thing when I started learning .NET 2.0.  I kept wondering, "What the hell does T mean, and why doesn't Visual Studio know what I'm trying to do?"

Comment: So if I want to have different types of objects in my list I need to use an interface, ie List<Ianimal>, so store catObj, and dogObj, for example?

Comment: [This Article][1] on MSDN should help you immensely. [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Comment: Yes, List<IAnimal> would be a good example of how one can leverage generics.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`List<T>` means `List<WhateverTypeYouWantItToBeAListOf>`. So for example:

If I have an Employee Class, and I wanted a collection of Employees, I could say:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

I could then add `Employee` Objects to that list, and have it be Type-safe and extend to however many employee objects I put in it.

Like so:

```
Employee emp1 = new Employee();
Employee emp2 = new Employee();

employeeList.Add(emp1);
employeeList.Add(emp2);
```

`employeeList` now holds `emp1` and `emp2` as objects.

There are several facets to generic collections, the most important being they provide an object independent way of having a... well... collection of objects.  They are type-safe; which means that any collection will consist of one type of object. You won't have a `Animal` instance inside of `List<Employee>` (unless, of course, Employee is a base class that `Animal` inherits from. At that point, however, you have bigger problems.

Programming with Generics is its own topic, worthy of (at least) one chapter in a book.  At a very high level, programming with generics provides another way to reuse code -- independent of any class hierarchy or implementation details of a specific class.

More information [here](http://missingmanuals.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/06/20/generics.html).

Comment: What's the name of `<>`? What are its use cases? What should I know about them regarding C# language?

Answer (score 11):

You need to substitute `T` for another Type such as `int`, `string` or a class of your creation:

```
List<int> values = new List<int>();

values.Add(1);
values.Add(2);

int secondNumber = values[1]; // Yay! No casting or boxing required!
```

Answer (score 7):

For example if you wanted a generic list of integers (`int`) you would write:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

`T` is a type parameter, that in your code should be an actual type.

Answer (score 6):

What makes a "generic list" generic is the fact, that you can use the same class to create a list of apples and a list of potatoes. Of course once you create a list with the `new` operator you have to decide what objects you want it to store and communicate your decision by putting the Type name of the objects you store in the `<>`.

The following line actually tells the compiler:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
```

"Hey, I need a list that can handle objects of type `Employee`; and is named `employeeList`!"

The list object you get that way is not generic anymore. It will only accept and return objects of type `Employee`. But the list's behavior is defined in a "generic" way that doesn't care about what objects it's actually working with. It just calls them '`T`' internally because for all that the list is supposed to do, it's contents type doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5):

Consider `T` as a variable name. You must specify its value, ie. make the generic class 'specific'. So, you can create `List<string>`, `List<int>`, or `List` of anything else you want.

Answer (score 4):

You declare a List of Foo objects like so:

```
List<Foo> fooList;
```

The  in the type name is a placeholder for the 'real' type of object you put in to the generic list at the time you instantiate it.

Answer (score 4):

When you do a `List<Object>`, make sure your Object class is public. In default VS installations, classes come out of the box as 'internal' - meaning you can't make a list of them because they're less accessible than the public List you're declaring.

This got me um... yesterday. Stupid defaults.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to use the List class or are you trying to build your own? What does your code look like at the moment?