# What is the use of <T> with almost every NEST query

Tags: c#, generics, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to `C#` and `NEST API`. I have done few projects using it but I'm not clear why the *class_name* / *POCO name* mentioned in every `NEST` Query.

Consider the following queries,

```
 - client.DeleteAsync<class_name>(id)
 - client.Delete<class_name>(id)
 - client.Search<class_name>(id)
```

What does the `class_name` have to do anything with the query? Please explain.

Comment: It's called Generic, and it's a way to avoid having the same code repeated for every class. Without generics, you would have: client.DeleteSomething and client.DeleteSomethingElse and client.DeleteMyClass etc... Have a search for C# generic you'll find plenty of information

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for NEST, as I think it answers your question: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html

Answer (score 0):

class_name is your poco class name.

which contain all get or set methods/fields name.

for `<T>`.

It's dynamic or generic type parameter.

You can pass any datatype into that.

refer this link for more clarification.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857180/what-does-t-denote-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think the OP was more asking _why_ methods in NEST take a generic type parameter, as opposed to _what_ a generic type parameter is.