# What do greater/less than sign (e.g. Action<List<X>>) mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

example:

```
public event Action<List<WKSProfile>> WorkstationProfileChanged;
```

I have trouble understanding the the above member. 
Does it imply that it returns :

```
Action<List<WKSProfile>>
```

Comment: They indicate Generics.

Comment: Did you look it up? This is documented in the language guide, under generics.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361336/what-are-generic-collections-in-c

Comment: @peachykeen - And if you never heard of generics? What would you search for?

Comment: @Oded: ["C# Types"](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+types), and [the second result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx) which mentions just this syntax. The OP seems to recognize that's where the type goes, so looking up type syntax is a great starting place.

Comment: @peachykeen - "The OP seems to recognize that's where the type goes". Where exactly? You are reading into it, methinks.

Comment: @Oded: "Does it imply that it returns..." Definitely recognizing that's where the return type goes, but unclear on whether this is one or just how the crazy <stuff> works. Thus, going to the reference on (return) types.

Comment: @peachykeen - That to me seems a copy-paste of the return type of the event/delegate signature, nothing more. It doesn't mean the OP knows that what goes between the `<>` is a type.

Comment: I am trying to say here that most people do not start up knowing all the terminology or even know how to use the terminology they do know in a correct way. Questions like this are legitimate - keep the beginners in mind.

Comment: @Oded: For the sake of argument, assuming the OP is not familiar with the structure of an event, then going to the [wikipedia page for C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) _and searching for <_ shows similar examples in the first result, and has "generics" in bold header text, for further research. _Minimal_ research would have answered this question.

Comment: It's very possible the OP didn't know and had trouble Googling for it (turns out searching for `<` and `>` isn't too easy), but I do think they should be encouraged to try and figure it out on their own, and it turns out to be pretty easy to find some information from even non-technical sources. Not to mention that, if you are familiar with the language structure or want to follow the rabbit hole of MSDN pages, you can find a fairly detailed account. For future reference, the OP should probably check there first, just in case.

Comment: @peachykeen I had trouble googling it but point noted :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the syntax to specify [generic type parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0zk36dx2.aspx).

> In a generic type or method definition, a type parameters is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type. A generic class, such as `GenericList<T>` listed in Introduction to Generics (C# Programming Guide), cannot be used as-is because it is not really a type; it is more like a blueprint for a type. To use `GenericList<T>`, client code must declare and instantiate a constructed type by specifying a type argument inside the angle brackets.